# Расшифровка данных dzip и deflate

Tags: php, кодировка, curl, gzip, deflate

cURL парсит страницу, но она приходит в сжатом виде. Среди headers, которые я отправляю, есть строчка `'Accept-Encoding: dzip, deflate'`, но, даже если ее убрать - результат не изменится. Пробовал декодировать полученную страницу с помощью декодера Лебедева - тщетно. Вот часть получаемого текста:

> ¬AY÷1¬ODA÷417¬XA÷d1¬XB÷d15¬XC÷d27¬ODA÷417¬ODC÷1¬ODB÷1¬ODD÷d¬ODC÷1¬ODB÷15¬ODD÷d¬ODC÷1¬ODB÷27¬ODD÷d¬~ZA÷

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь, который час бьюсь над этой проблемой!

Answer (score 2):

`cURL` умеет самостоятельно и отправлять `Accept-Encoding` и декодировать соответствующий ответ. В PHP экспортирована константа [`CURLOPT_ENCODING` для `curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). Для использования этого функционала вы должны вместо отправки заголовка `Accept-Encoding` вручную включить функционал `curl`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");
```

---

Впрочем, остаётся вероятность, что HTTP сервер с которым вы разговариваете не соблюдает стандарт, раз если вы не заявили `Accept-Encoding`, а всё равно получили сжатый текст. В этом случае и алгоритм сжатия можно ожидать любой.

Comment: пробовал оставлять две строчки, убирать по одной - не выходит

Comment: какие заголовки ответа получаете?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через [gzinflate](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gzinflate.php):

```
$url = "тут урл"

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

$return = curl_exec($ch); 
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

$return = gzinflate(substr($return, 10));
print_r($return);
```

Comment: Warning: gzinflate(): data error in... в гугле также ответа по этому поводу не нашел(